# Download Image from web

Tags: android, image

I have images on server named by email so when i try to download them on my application the @ symbol not shown on the path, is there anyway to stop escape this symbol ?

Example :
Correct Path
`Http://www.xxxxx.com/a@a.com.jpg`

Wrong Path
`Http://www.xxxxx.com/aa.com.jpg`

I tried URL encode but its not useful in my case

```
Bitmap downloadFile(String fileUrl) {
    URL myFileUrl = null;
    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    try {
        myFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        // imView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmImg;

}
```

Comment: Share the code for how you generate the URI.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini i update the question, i think my code is correct but URL did not accept @ symbol so my image url became wrong.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) from Android SDK.

```
try {
    myFileUrl = new URL(java.net.URLEncoder.encode(fileUrl));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just saw my mistake. That won't work because it's encoding the entire URL.

You have to separate the email address from the rest of the url like this.

```
    myFileUrl = new URL("http://www.xxxx.com/"+java.net.URLEncoder.encode(email));
```

Or alternatively, just replace the problem character.

```
    myFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl.replace("@","%40"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but i figured out the main problem, the server sent url with wrong backslashes (http:\/\/www.xxxx.com//)